# Android imageview onclick for several views

Tags: android, arrays, onclick, imageview

Question: I have a class with 300-400 imageviews. The class implements the View.onClickListener. Can i put the imageviews in some sort of array or ?
The imageviews are set up something like this

```
ImageView IM1 = new ImageView(this);  
IM1.setImageResource(R.drawable.have_fun);
```

and i cant understand how to use these in the onclick for the class. I have normally used getId but these dont have id since they arent in xml.

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<ImageView> imageViews = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
imageViews.add(IM1);
// add others ...
for(ImageView imgView : imageViews){
    IM1.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

And in the onClick Method you can compare View v with your ImageViews to decide what to do.

```
public void onClick(View v){
    if((ImageView)v == IM1){
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, if IM1 is your ImageView then:

```
IM1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
        /*your code here*/
        return true;
    }
});
```

Or if you want to handle only onClick, then

```
IM1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        /*your code here*/
    }
});
```

Difference is that with onTouch event you can handle also "move" and "drag" action. onTouch  called while your finger over the ImageView. onClick - only once you clicked.

Or you can create another class that implements interface OnClickListener, for example:

```
public class TouchController implements OnClickListener{

    /*any code that you need*/

    public void onClick(View v){
        /*your code*/
    }
}
```

and then

```
TouchController controller = new TouchController();
IM1.setOnClickListener(controller);
```

Comment: That is onTouch, he wants onClick.

Comment: Is onClick and onTouch the same ?

Comment: Ok, but arent there any easier way to write the code then write a onclick for each image and set each imageview up by`ImageView IM1 = new ImageView(this);  
IM1.setImageResource(R.drawable.have_fun);` ? Cant i use the implement onclick.. ?

Comment: @Hello, added example to my answer

Answer (score 0):

you can use tags for the view.

set a integer tag for the imageView

```
ImageView IM1 = new ImageView(this);  
IM1.setImageResource(R.drawable.have_fun);
IM1.setTag(1);
```

and in onClickListener, you have reference to the view that is clicked, you can decide which image is clicked using

```
   int imageClicked = (int) clickedView.getTag();
```

compare the `imageClicked` to know which image has been clicked.

Comment: Ok, can do something like this in onclick if a want a switch public void onClick(View v){
     switch (v.getTag)
     }
 }

Comment: yes, you can do it :) , but you may have to cast it to integer.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the images you could set an id dynamically:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < listImages.size(); i++) {
        final ImageView image = listImages.get(i);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.have_fun);
        image.setId(i);
    }
```

And then in your onClick method you could do:

```
OnClickListener onClick = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {

        }
    }
};
```